# RegExp that will replace any matching word which is not part of a decimal value

Tags: javascript, regex

Until now this has worked well for me to find and remove words from a string but unfortunately it is also matching single digits of numbers that are part of a larger decimal number. how can I modify my Reg Expr to not match on decimal numbers but treat any other, non numerical occurrence of '.' as a word parser?
    `

```js
$("#123").val(removeSubstring("this should be removed: 9. But not 9.9 or 1.9 or 9.1 or 999 but it should remove this 9 and this 9,too!","9"));

function removeSubstring(lookIn,subStringToRemove){
 
 
   return lookIn.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + subStringToRemove + "\\b","gi"),"");
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id=123 style="width: 100%;"></input>
```

Desired output should be "`this should be removed: . But not 9.9 or 1.9 or 9.1 or 999 but it should remove this  and this ,too!`." So two of the "9" should be removed only.

Comment: Try `.replace(new RegExp("(\\d*\\.?\\d+)|\\b" + subStringToRemove + "\\b","gi"),"$1")`

Comment: Given the above input, what is the expected output?

Comment: Jordan, the desired output should be: "this should be removed: . But not 9.9 or 1.9 or 9.1 or 999". Thanks for looking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this looks very promising but it does not actually change the string. The output is : `this should be removed: 9. But not 9.9 or 1.9 or 9.1 or 999`. That is, the "..9." is not matched and removed. Thank you.

Comment: just edited the above snippet to clarify that any "9" should be removed if the character immediately before or after is not a number or a decimal character. I suspect I might be limited by jscript RegX not being able to look behind

Comment: So, `subStringToRemove` is a number as a string? Try `.replace(new RegExp("(^|[^\\d.])" + subStringToRemove + "(?![.\\d])","g"),"$1")`

Comment: That's right, it's a number as a string....thank you, that expression almost does the trick in all scenarios EXCEPT the first " 9. ". Ideally it would replace that character as well because the trailing "." represents a full stop, as opposed to "9.0", which otherwise it rightly would ignore. I could live with this, though, if it's as close as we can get?

Comment: It seems really difficult to do this job only with a replace using regex, i would suggest you to split your string by the `" "` character and then perform a regex.match on all resulting array elements to check if it has to proceed with the substitution: e.g.
i would use this regex to match if the input is a valid number:
`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9])*$`
and then in case it is i'll simply perform a `string.replace("9","")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Lemmy4555 and I had gone down various similar routes before posting the question but it was just making the code too complicated ( the containing function also dealt with other scenarios, some of which would break the more I manually manipulated the string. Maciej solution seems to do the trick; as does Wiktor except for the one exception, so the former gets the tick. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove any number of digits followed by dot or comma keeping dot and comma this should work for you:

### Solution

```
data.replace(/\d+(\.|\,\D?)/g, '$1')
```

### How it works

`\d+` find any number of digits.
`\.|\,` find '.' or ','
`\D?` find one or zero of not digit characters.
`()` create capture group.

`$1` use content of first capture group while replacing.

[Check if it works for you.](https://regex101.com/r/SP1QJ4/1)

Comment: You know, I rather think it does! Thank you very much, and for taking the time to explain the expression. You llinked to example presented as php (uh oh, I thought) but when I changed to javascript it still worked (wahoo!). Updated link [link](https://regex101.com/r/SP1QJ4/2)

Comment: All regex works almost same and yeah I forgot to change it to js but it doesn't matter for simple operations. I'm happy that you appreciatey my work :)

Answer (score 0):

using negative lookbehind

```
(?<!\.|\d)9(?!\.\d|\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/an8eg1/1

But this not work in javascript.